# An error has occurred. Please retry later message when uploading pdf files for online UK Visa application

Tags: visas, uk

My wife is studying an MBA in Germany, as part of this MBA the students are given the option of attending a one-week course in the UK, my wife is applying for a short-term visa to the UK to attend this course.

When she tries to upload her documents in pdf format in the online visa application she keeps getting this error: "An error has occurred. Please retry later."

Has anyone faced this problem before and found a solution?

**Finally we found a solution, we re-created the pdfs that we couldn´t upload and tried again, this time it worked.**

Much obliged!

Comment: What possible solutions have you tried already eg using a different browser, clearing cache etc

Comment: I have tried using Safari browser in a Mac, Chrome, Chrome in incognito mode, DuckDuckGo y Edge in a PC, all with the same result.

Comment: Is there a size limit? one thing I would try is simply compressing the pdf file using any online pdf compression website and try with the compressed file.

Comment: The files are less than 1mb in size and I have succesfully uploaded another 3 pdf files that are bigger :(